# How to change an association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to know if I build an association between two models and later find out that I should change it, what should I do then? For example, if there is a has_one and belongs_to associations between two models and then I find out that it should be has_many, what should I do? Should I create a new migration, beside changing those terms in the models' files? If so, what should I write inside the migration file? where else should I make changes?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you had:

```
class Foo
 has_many :bars #or has_one :bar
end
```

Another class:

```
class Bar
 belongs_to :foo
end
```

On your database, you'll need to add a column `foo_id` on your bars table but you won't need `bar_id` column on your foos table. So if you decide to transpose the relationship, just need to add that column on foos table.

I would recommend that you plan things out first before running migrations.

Kinda like:

```
    1) Foo
         - post:string
         - somethingelse:integer

         has_many :bars or has_one :bar

    2) Bar
         - something:boolean
         - else:string
         - foo_id:integer

         belongs_to :foo
```

Now you know what to run when you create your models you can run migrations right away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For sure, planning ahead, is the best way. But in the cases that I need to change the codes written by someone else, I wanted to know if I need to rollback? or create a new migration?

Comment: I would just add the columns that I need to get the job done, so new migrations are what you need

Comment: Then I suppose that for removing some associations, I would also need to generate new migrations and in them, remove columns. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you can remove unneeded columns

Comment: Can you add the correct Migration for that issue? I wonder how you structure your migration in that case and how you manage to buffer the given (already correct) association. Would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change from `has_one` to `has_many`, then I think all you need to do is change the association is your model to `has_many`, however if you want to change the `belongs_to`, that's when you will need to rollback that specific migration and create a new one according to the new association

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no changes needed to the data files... you already have a foreign key in the `has_one (singular)` target model, so you can just change it to a `has_many (plural)`in the model definition.

Where you reference the association, for example `book.owner` you would have to use the plural term `book.owners` and the response will be an array of objects instead of a single object.

All your existing relationships will automatically change... where you had one owner for a book, you'll still have one owner of a book but it'll be in an array and you'll be able to add more owners now.